# Connect to SQL Server via Python

Tags: sql, python-3.x

I am a beginner at Python and I want to connect to SQL Server with it. I use VS Code editor to write my codes with Python 3.9.6.

I want to know there is any library for doing it or not? And if it is yes, which function or command should use for connecting to the database?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pyodbc` to connect to SQL Server.
Install this using the command

> pip install pyodbc

Now after installing you can use this sample code to learn how to connect to your db

```
import pyodbc 
# Some other example server values are
# server = 'localhost\sqlexpress' # for a named instance
# server = 'myserver,port' # to specify an alternate port
server = 'tcp:myserver.database.windows.net' 
database = 'mydb' 
username = 'myusername' 
password = 'mypassword' 
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
```

To Run A Query you can Use the following code snippet

```
#Sample select query
cursor.execute("SELECT @@version;") 
row = cursor.fetchone() 
while row: 
    print(row[0])
    row = cursor.fetchone()
```

You can follow this link to learn more. [How to Connect Python to SQL Server using pyodbc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/python/pyodbc/step-3-proof-of-concept-connecting-to-sql-using-pyodbc?view=sql-server-ver15)

Answer (score 1):

A very commonly used Python library for interacting with databases is SQLAlchemy. Specific to your question, SQLAlchemy does support SQL Server. Here's how you would [connect to SQL Server](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/engines.html#microsoft-sql-server) using SQLAlchemy.

[This is a good starting point](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/tutorial.html#connecting) on how to use SQLAlchemy to talk to a database. Just be aware, SQLAlchemy is a world unto itself. It's really a whole additional set of skills you have to learn on top of Python so just be prepare to spend time learning it in addition to Python.